# How do you get the title of an html page in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, title

I've currently got a website in which a div is updated to the contents of the same div on another page via Javascript, allowing a seamless transition between webpages, but how do I make the title of the webpage update to the title of the new webpage?

Further clarification: I know how to change the title of the webpage, but how do I get the title of a specified webpage?

Comment: You mean you would like to get the titel of another HTML document?

Comment: How do you get the `div`? Is it in an `iframe`?

Comment: Yes pretty much. And I'm using jQuery to load the div, and no, it's not an iframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get/set `document.title`.

```
document.title = "New Title For Page";
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make that clear. As in my edit,  I know how to change the title of the webpage, but how do I get the title of a specified webpage?

Comment: @BenElgar well, you can get or set. To get : `var t = document.title;` To set : `document.title = 'value';`

Comment: But how do I set document to be the new webpage without actually reloading the page?

Comment: @BenElgar the process of setting `document` to be a new page **is** reloading the page. You can load a piece of another page into an existing page, but completely updating the page is literally what "reloading the page" means.

Comment: @BenElgar if the other page is one in your domain, then you can fetch it with an XHR and get whatever you want from it. If it's in a different domain, you can only do that if the source site is set up to allow it (CORS headers).

Answer (score 1):

```
var newWindow = window.open("www.site.com","Title","options...");
newWindow.title = "rename here";
```

Comment: As I understand it that would open a new window with a specified title. What I would like to do is to change the title of a webpage to that of another specified webpage for which I have the URL.

Comment: Okey.. Add a frame into your html codes. Redirect frame to specified webpage. And get frame title. How to ? "frame1.document.title". Ok ?